# delete data from firebase using key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my first time using firebase. My database looks like:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBhKf.png)

I have the key and would like to remove the node for that key:

```
var dataKey = $("#trainClicked").attr("data-key");
var ref = database.ref("trains/" + changeTrain);
ref.on('value', function (snapshot) {
console.log(snapshot)
    if (snapshot === null) {
        console.log("does not exist")
    } else {
        return database.ref().remove(dataKey)
   }
});
```

This removes the entire database and gives an error:

```
return database.ref().remove(dataKey)
```

I have read through firebase docs and through many posts here but I still cant get it to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answer below. But I have a quick question, since you're not the first with this approach in recent weeks. Where did you get the idea from that calling `remove(dataKey)` will remove `dataKey`? If it was our documentation that somehow steered you into that direction, I'd love to improve it.

Comment: directly from the firebase docs

Comment: I will try to find the exact page

Comment: @Frank - here is the link: 
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data

Comment: Thanks for that link. I don't see any mistakes in there, so it must be a matter of clarity. Do you have any suggestion how we could make it clearer (without making it too much longer), given [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49454248/209103) below?

Comment: You guys rarely show what the database looks like, ie when you start an example - what was the root? where is the key?  For complete beginners like myself,  it ends up being rather useless because we don't know where to start. A link to the github page showing the whole database and code would be VERY helpful.  The links I did find dump you in a directory and I can never find the code I was looking for.

Comment: Also you guys started the videos for complete beginners - which was nice - but they were adding/deleting directly in firebase. My entire class was commenting on where were the videos doing the same thing from js.  That is what we cant figure out and where we need help.  Sorry for the novel..  ;)

Comment: No apologies needed, this is most helpful. Good point on the Github links. You'll be able to find the code with ctrl-F, but indeed we should just deeplink straight to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Reference.remove()` doesn't take any arguments, but instead removes the data at the reference you call it on. Since you're calling `remove()` on the root of the database, all data gets removed.

You're looking for `ref.remove()` or `snapshot.ref.remove()` here.

Comment: I tried both of those ( in the else {....   But nothing happens.  On the up side, no error message either.

Comment: The `else` block in the code you shared calls `remove` on the root database reference. If you've tried something else and it doesn't work, share that code. But it it stopped deleting the entire database, I'd consider that progress. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simply run an empty `.set()` command on that node. That will delete everything. If you run an empty `.set()` you will delete your entire database. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that works:

```
var dataKey = $("#train-clicked").attr("data-key");
    var ref = database.ref("trains/" + dataKey)
    ref.once('value', function (snapshot) {
        if (snapshot === null) {
            console.log("does not exist")
        } else {
         snapshot.ref.remove();
        }
```

Changing the snapshot.ref.remove() line but also changing ref.on to ref.once....  when it was .on it worked once but it was giving an error because it was trying to read something that wasnt there any more (I think).